# SMTPSenderRefused in Django 1.7, when reset password

Tags: python, django

First, I use Django 1.6 and I have update it to 1.7. In 1.6 everything works fine.

**urls.py:**

```
url(r'^password/reset/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset', {}, 'password_reset'),
```

**password_reset_form.html:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">{% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span>
      <input class="form-control" id="inputEmail" maxlength="25" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" pattern=".{7,}" required>
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Reset Password</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

When I send this form I have an error:

```
SMTPSenderRefused at /password/reset/
(553, '5.7.1 Sender address rejected: not owned by auth user.', u'webmaster@localhost')
```

**Traceback:**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/password/reset/

Django Version: 1.7.1
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'sorl.thumbnail',
 'django_cron',
 'my_app',
 'django.contrib.admin')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  105.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py" in password_reset
  163.             form.save(**opts)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py" in save
  276.             send_mail(subject, email, from_email, [user.email], html_message=html_email)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py" in send_mail
  62.     return mail.send()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py" in send
  286.         return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py" in send_messages
  99.                 sent = self._send(message)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py" in _send
  115.             self.connection.sendmail(from_email, recipients, message.as_bytes(linesep='\r\n'))
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py" in sendmail
  724.             raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)

Exception Type: SMTPSenderRefused at /password/reset/
Exception Value: (553, '5.7.1 Sender address rejected: not owned by auth user.', u'webmaster@localhost')
```

I think, that problem in **send_email()**, in my **settings.py** I have no **webmaster@localhost**.

How to fix that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

Sorry for noob-question.

in **settings.py**:

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

Answer (score 0):

When I had this same issue, I was using environment variables for my EMAIL_HOST_USER and EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD. After restarting my VirtualBox, these variables (placed inside ~/.profile) starting working and I didn't get this error anymore.